# Data frame/vector context in R

Tags: regex, r

Not sure how to explain what I'm asking for, but here is an example of code:

```
aat<-as.character(lapply(
    list.files(), 
    function(i) { 
        if(regexpr('new\\_mailed',i,ignore.case=T)>0) { 
            return(i); 
        } 
    }
))
```

basically, this will return `NULL` if the filename in the current iteration doesn't satisfy the regex.

what I want to do is do `as.character(..all that code here..)[only get items where not equal to NULL]` without having to assign to a variable and then do `variable[variable != NULL]`

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use `list.files(pattern = "new\\_mailed")`